# Unexpected behavior of strokeStyle in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working on a Javascript graphing library in javascript, and I have a function that draws the grid, with each gridline having one color, and the axes having another color.
The relevant code is at this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F5LPn/#run 
The main method that is being called is at the bottom, as the top has to load.

```
var ctx=document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.line(0,0,5,5);
ctx.lineWidth=1;
ctx.setGraph(-10,10,-10,10,1,1);
ctx.drawGraph('lightgrey','black');
ctx.strokeStyle='pink';
ctx.line(0,0,5,5);
```

The drawGraph method uses this code

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawGraph=function(color,axiscolor){
alert('called!');
this.strokeStyle=color;
for(var i=this.xmin;i<=this.xmax;i+=this.xscl){
    this.line(i,this.xmin,i,this.xmax);
}
for(var j=this.ymin;j<=this.ymax;j+=this.yscl){
    this.line(this.ymin,j,this.ymax,j);
}
//  this.strokeStyle=axiscolor;
this.line(0,this.xmin,0,this.xmax);
this.line(this.ymin,0,this.ymax,0);
this.strokeStyle=color;
};
```

As you can see, at least in my browser, even though the strokestyle is being set to green after the drawgraph is called, the whole grid is colored green. I have no clue why this is happening

Thanks

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working for me.

Comment: Fixed your fiddle (jsfiddle does the body onload stuff internally): http://jsfiddle.net/F5LPn/3/

Comment: Also not the issue, but you shouldn't `closePath` on a straight line, and adding methods to the built-in context object is asking for trouble. Just make helper functions or wrap the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you don't `beginPath` in your `line` function. So your grid actually gets drawn twice; once in lightgrey and once in pink, because in the line call, it still has all the data for the grid lines.

Aside from that, you shouldn't add methods to a built-in object (especially in a library)

Comment: I'm fairly new to the world of programming, but what's wrong with adding methods to an object?

Comment: It means that a developer who uses your object might accidentally call your methods when they intend to call a standard method (especially if you give it the same name, and if the standards change to add more methods you might get name collision in the future). It's also slower at runtime in some browsers (I'll try to find the stats I saw).

Comment: What can I do to get around that?

Comment: Here's a similar question, which has a suggestion in the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1454089/1180785

Comment: Ok thanks. I get it now. Is it also possible to do ctx.mycompanyname.prototype.line=function() blah blah

Comment: no, but you could do `ctx.prototype.mycompanyname = {'line':function(){blah},'somethingElse':function(){blah}}`, which would be called as `myContext.mycompanyname.line()`, etc. The syntax starts to get a bit convoluted. My personal preference is to just define an object or set of functions in its own right, and pass the context to it; `myLineDrawingFunction(context,0,1,10,1)`

Comment: actually I think that wouldn't work, because you'd have the wrong `this` object in the function… something like that could be done with a bit of work, but I'd still recommend not adding methods to it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm not able to run your code - only the graph container rectangle gets drawn - but i normally do this to switch colors while drawing:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "colorValue";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(sx, sy);
ctx.lineTo(ex, ey);
ctx.stroke();
```

Then again:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "colorValue";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(sx, sy);
ctx.lineTo(ex, ey);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: What browser/os are you using?

Comment: Mac OSX 10.8.3 + Chrome 26